# Android Glide download before display

Tags: android, image, download, android-glide

I'm using Glide and I want to know if it's possible to download all images without display them to fill the cache to display them later ? I tried this but the images are not downloaded :

```
for (String url: urls) {
    Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(url);
    Log.v("Download", "processing");
}
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my problem we can use this to download the images :

```
Glide
   .with( context )
   .load( "http://futurestud.io/icon.png" )
   .downloadOnly(2000, 2000);
```

And to get and display the images in the cache, we should use the same url and add the diskCacheStrategy parameter like this :

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load( "http://futurestud.io/icon.png" )
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use asBitmap method in Glide to do the same.

```
Glide.with(this).
        load(url).
        asBitmap().
        into(100, 100). // Width and height
        get();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I see the images download now but when I call the same urls when I display them, they are re-download I don't know why.

Comment: I think with this way the images are not saved in the same place :/

Answer (score 0):

Glide version 4.6.1

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions().priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE);

Glide.with(appContext)
        .download(model)
        .apply(requestOptions)
        .submit();
```